# How do I start manipulating the data that is entered? I just can't find out where to start

Tags: java, arrays, mean, temp

So I'm making a program for a Java class, and need to find the mean, mode, max, min, and median of a set of temperatures that I enter. Here's what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Temps {
    private int temp[] = new int[5];
    String inputStr;
    int inputInt = 0;

    public void startApp()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        {
            inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new temp.");
            inputInt = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
            temp[i] = inputInt; 
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Temps obj = new Temps();
        obj.startApp();     

    } 
}
```

Where and how do I start manipulating the values in the array? I have no idea where to start, and any help would be awesome.

Comment: Start by thinking about how you would calculate the mean/mode/max/min and create a method for each

Comment: would I put the method underneath public static void main or above it as part of startApp()?

Comment: The position of a method in a class isn't critical to the functioning of the method. I'd recommend one method for each thing you are trying to do eg; calculateMean, calculateMode, getMinimumTemp, getMaximumTemp

Comment: Position isnt important as beresfordt mentioned, but for readability/organization, above main. Each method should return the calculated value. You can then call them in main to output, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have completed the mean method for you just so you can see how it should be done. I am guessing you can figure out the rest on your own based on my code. Note: it is not the most efficient or elegant way to do it, but it gets the job done. Good luck.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Temps {
    private static int temp[] = new int[5];
    String inputStr;
    int inputInt = 0;

    public void startApp() {
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new temp.");
            inputInt = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
            temp[i] = inputInt;
        }
    }

    public static int meanMethod(int temp[]) {

        int mean, sum;
        mean = 0;
        sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            sum += temp[i];
            if (i == (temp.length - 1)) {
                mean = sum / temp.length;
                return mean;
            }
        }
        return mean;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Temps obj = new Temps();
        obj.startApp();
        System.out.println(obj.meanMethod(temp));

        /*

        You could do JOptionPane instead of System.out.println here. Just do:

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, obj.meanMethod(temp));

        */

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you one method to get you started. Suppose your array is `int[] nums = {1,1,2,2,3};`

We know the mean is calculated as (1+1+2+2+3)/5 = 9/5 = 1.8, and here's a method that does exactly that:

```
public double calculateMean(int[] nums) {
    double sum = 0; //<--if you use int here, your value would be 1.0 not 1.8
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        sum += nums[i];
    }
    return sum / nums.length;
}
```

You can use it in your main method:

```
int[] nums = {1,1,2,2,3};
double d = calculateMean(nums);
System.out.println(d); //the result is 1.8
```